# Terminology: bounded curve

Tags: curves

Is it the convention to say that a curve $\gamma$ is *bounded* if it's entirely contained in a bounded set in, say $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

**Edit:**
If we forget about the strict convention of terminology, would **you** understand what I meant buy a *bounded* curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read about a bounded curve then yes, I'd assume it is entirely contained in a bounded set.